# Why is DexNav suddenly taking a long time to find Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

After I caught my Shiny Wurmple using the Dexnav method the Dexnav has been working poorly. It might take 5 min to get a successful Pokémon search or I might not find anything.

Is this a bug? Or could I be doing something wrong?

Comment: Sounds like the DexNav to me. Takes a few tries every time.

Answer (score 1):

When the DexNav says that "It couldn't find a Pokémon" it doesn't necessarily mean that the chain has ended. If you leave the route and re-enter then you will break the chain.

Leaving the route per se doesn't re-activate the DexNav. When the DexNav fails you have to walk a few steps (20-30) before it activates again, so do that and the DexNav will be usable again.

The problem you're having is that the DexNav just keeps failing. That means you keep searching in a bad spot. Keep in mind that Pokémon do not spawn within a 5 tile radius of you, so if you search in the center of a small patch of grass the DexNav is very likely to fail.
Find a better spot to use the DexNav and keep returning to it after each chain battle.

Answer (score 0):

Your captures/encounters should have no bearing on DexNav - however there are some things that will break a DexNav chain:

1. Running into another type of Pokemon (use Repels!)
2. Fleeing from a battle
3. Missing/Scaring a chained Pokemon
4. Getting the 'No Pokemon found in this area' message. (You have to leave the area and come back in order to reset this message, which in itself will reset the chain).

To maximise your chances to avoid point 4, stand in large patches of grass, or areas with a lot of surrounding grass. For example, in places like Route 116, walk to the Grass-less area where all the patches in the area are in sight.

Also note that the longer a chain is running, the shorter amount of time you have to get to the encounter